# Two custom source in Pine inputs

Tags: pine-script

Has anybody found a (creative) way to combine the input of two custom indicators in pine? It appears that if two source inputs are used one can only select OHLC's as inputs?

Example:

```
a = input(close , 'input a')
b = input(close , 'input a')
c = a > b ? 1: 0
plot(c)
```

vs

```
a = input(close , 'input a')
c = a > 0 ? 1: 0
plot(c)
```

In the first version you can only select OHLC as input vs the second where you can select any plotline. This is a pretty severe limitation when stacking algo's.

Comment: It's imposible to use two inputs from different indicators. This limitation was put there intentionally in a way to save performance, otherwise such scripts create too bit load on tradingview's servers.

Comment: Is this something that can be improved on in future versions? In my naive understanding each script/ input needs to be calculated only once top down (historically per bar, real-time per tick). If you limit the allowed inputs to the prior indicators there doesn't seem any risk of self-referencing or recursion?

Comment: Yes, it's planned to improve in future versions, but without ETA, unfortunatelly.